# To add information about the customer to a shopping cart in android using soap api

Tags: android

```
      I am getting an error such as SoapFault - faultcode: '1045' faultstring: 'Customer's mode is unknown' faultactor: 'null' detail: null 
      Please anyone could help me. 

           SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"shoppingCartCustomerEntity");

       // customerEntity.addProperty("entity_id","23");
        customerEntity.addProperty("firstname","Deepti");
        customerEntity.addProperty("lastname","D");
        customerEntity.addProperty("email","abcd@gmail.com");

        customerEntity.addProperty("website_id", 0);
        customerEntity.addProperty("store_id",0);
        customerEntity.addProperty("mode","guest");

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCustomerSet");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        request.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
        request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        (new MarshalHashtable()).register(env);

        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Boolean customerAddressAdded = (Boolean) env.getResponse();

        Log.d("Customer Info ", customerAddressAdded.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try customer instead of customerData

```
-request.addProperty("customerData", customerEntity);  
+request.addProperty("customer", customerEntity);
```